# When and where does Intern.js opens browser and how to open a new browser by using intern script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, uiautomation

I'm trying my hands at intern.js to automate my UI test. And I want to some test to run on a separate browser, i.e

1. open new browser run test
2. run test
3. close browser

and so on

but I'm unable to figure out when or where does intern script open browser, and how can I open a new browser window by running selenium script.

Heres my code:

intern.js

```
   define({
proxyPort: 9000,
proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
capabilities: {
    'selenium_version': '2.48.2',
}, 
environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome', version: '48', platform: [ 'WINDOWS' ] },
],
maxConcurrency: 3,

tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
 reporters: [
     {id:'Runner'},
        {id:'Console'},
    ], 
   Loaders: {
    'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
    'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
},
loaderOptions: {
    packages: [ { name: 'intern-tutorial', location: '.' } ]
},
functionalSuites: [
'Automation/test/login/loginpagetest'
],
defaultTimeout: 610000,
excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
 });
```

loginpagetest.js

```
 // in tests/functional/index.js
define([
'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'Automation/ConfigFiles/dataurl',
'Automation/pages/login/loginpage',
'intern/dojo/node!fs',
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
], function (registerSuite, assert,dataurl, LoginPage,fs,pollUntil) {
registerSuite(function () {
    var loginPage;
    var values;
    return {
        // on setup, we create an IndexPage instance
        // that we will use for all the tests
        setup: function () {
            var data = fs.readFileSync(loginpage, 'utf8');
            json=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('####################Setting Up Login Page Test#######################')
            values = json.values;
           return this.remote
                .get(require.toUrl(json.locator.URL)).setFindTimeout(6000000000).sleep(5000)
        },

        'successful login': function () {
            console.log('####################Login Success Test#######################')
            loginPage = new LoginPage(this.remote,json.locator);
             loginPage
                .login(values.unamevalue,values.pwdvalue)
            var loginSuccess = loginPage.isLoginSuccess();
            assert.isTrue(loginSuccess, 'Login Failed');
         },
        'failed login': function () {
          // test faild login
        },
      };
    });
 });
```

loginpage.js

```
  define(function (require) {
  
   function LoginPage(remote,locator) {
    this.remote = remote;
    this.locator = locator;
}

LoginPage.prototype = {
    constructor: LoginPage,

    login: function (username, password) {
        return this.remote
            .findById(this.locator.uname)
            .then(function () {
                return true;
            })
            .type(username).click() // for QABOX //
            .end()
            .findById(this.locator.nextbtn).sleep(3000)
            .click().end()
            .findById(this.locator.pwd).sleep(3000)
            .type(password).click()
            .end()
            .findById(this.locator.login).click()
            .end()
    },
    isLoginSuccess:function() {
        return this.remote.findById('dashboard');
    }

    };

  return LoginPage;
 });
```

In the loginpage test, I want to run `successfull login` in the seperate browser and close browser when the test is complete and `failed login` in another browser and close browser when the test is complete/ How can I achieve that? Can any one help??

Comment: Did you ever figure out what you were trying to do?